# is that a special string format of Javascript

Tags: javascript

When I am reading some codes of Javascript, I stop at this below:

```
object1.A = {
    ...
    port:"<%= @port1 %>"
    ...
}
```

Is that some kind of special string format of Javascript like Ruby "#{port1}" which can convert to the specific value automaticlly ?

Comment: Nope, but it looks like http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: Either that's ASP or custom PHP tag

Answer (score 3):

No, this is nothing special in a JavaScript context, but might however be processed and subsituted on the server side by another scripting language, or by a client side templating library.

Answer (score 0):

```
object1.A = {
    ...
    port:"<%= @port1 %>"
    ...
}
```

Has not really to do with javascript itself. I guess it is some kind of templating (language).
Maybe it has to do with serverside templating like `ASP`, or `JSP` or the like. On the other hand you have template strings in [Backbone](http://underscorejs.org/#template) which use such a notation.
But the `@`-sign suggests something ruby-like (cf. [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)).